# Invoke-Command ignores #requires in the script file

Tags: powershell, require

We've written some scripts that need to be called with `Invoke-Command` to run on remote machines. These scripts contain some `$Requires` lines at the top. However, it seems when running them with `Invoke-Command -FilePath` that the `#Requires` strings are just completely ignored.

**Script.ps1**

```
#Requires -Version 9

[CmdLetBinding()]
Param (
    [String[]]$Path
)

'Success'
```

**Execution code:**

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath '.\Script.ps1' -ComputerName localhost
```

No error is thrown, although we would expect the `#Requires` to not be met. So the script shouldn't run at all.

Comment: `#` is a single line comment in PowerShell. The entire line will be ignored. I didn't understand your problem correctly. Where is `$Requires` in your code?

Comment: Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-6) to get a better understanding of `#Requires`

Comment: And, what is your question?

Comment: Why `#Requires` is not throwing an error when the script is called with `Invoke-Command -FilePath` and it does when called with `& '.\Script.ps1'`. It should throw in both cases..

Comment: #Requires only applied to files, but not to script blocks. [`Get-Help Invoke-Command -Parameter FilePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command?view=powershell-5.1): *When you use this parameter, Windows PowerShell converts the contents of the specified script file to a script block, transmits the script block to the remote computer, and runs it on the remote computer.*

Comment: Thx @PetSerAl I missed that part of conversion. This is the correct answer.